# Change picture in grid on click in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I've filled grid with Images in code and I'm tryig to add mouse events to them

```
public FilesWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                Image image = new Image();
                image.MouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(setPicture);
                myGrid.Children.Add(image);
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(randomPic());
                Grid.SetRow(image, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(image, j);
            }
        }
    }

private void setPicture(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

but I don't know how to access this specyfic Image (the one I click). Clicking itself (ex. with writing on console) is working but how to change picture in a cell that was clicked?

Comment: `sender` would be the Image (the one you click)

Comment: do a type cast, `(sender as Image)`, since sender is of type object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast `sender` (which is type `object`) to `Image`:

```
Image image = (Image)sender;
```